# Optimal way to check list in Kotlin is unique

Tags: kotlin, collections

What would be the best way to check whether values of a list (or iterable) are unique? I keep finding answers suggesting `distinct()` or `distinctBy {}`, however I do NOT want to modify the list, just to check it.

Model use case: user is adding some data, before saving them I need to validate uniqueness, however in case of failed validation I cannot determine which data to remove (they may contain additional data such as user notes), I need just to tell the user the input is not valid and why and let them to decide which items to remove.

My solution would be smth like this:

```
  list.groupBy { it.id }.none { it.value.size > 1 }
```

but I wonder whether there is a better (more Kotlin-like) way, perhaps some library function &c.

**Note:** I cannot ensure the data have equals and hashCode implemented, thus the obvious way of putting them in the set and comparing sizes is not applicable.

Comment: "I cannot ensure the data have equals and hashCode implemented". How then do you propose checking uniqueness? Uniqueness implies values can be compared.

Comment: `distinct()` does not modify the original list...

Comment: @Nicolas: Item id is obviously comparable, just not the whole item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More optimal way to do it (with lazy evaluation which will return `false` on a first met duplicate and skip processing the rest of collection):

```kotlin
inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.allUniqueBy(transform: (T) -> R): Boolean {
    val hashset = hashSetOf<R>()
    return this.all { hashset.add(transform(it)) }
}

//Usage:
list.allUniqueBy { it.id }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can't compare the data as a whole, but you can compare IDs, then you can throw those in a set!

```
list.map { it.id }.toSet().size == list.size
```

I mean that's what you're checking really right, how many unique IDs there are

Answer (score 0):

Started writing an answer to Nicolas' comment and then it occurred to me that simple:

```
list.map { it.id }.let { ids -> ids.size == ids.toSet().size }
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Shorter and more efficient version of this: `list.distinctBy { it.id }.size == list.size`

Comment: Even `distinctBy` is not terribly efficient, since it creates a set but must return a list. Better would be `list.mapTo(mutableSetOf()) { it.id }.size == list.size`.